# Proxmox with OPNsense as Firewall/GW - routing issue

Tags: linux, networking, routes, proxmox, opnsense

This setup should be based on a proxmox, being behind a opnsense VM hosted on the Proxmox itself which will protect proxmox, offer a firewall, a privat LAN and DHCP/DNS to the VMs and offer a IPsec connection into the LAN to access all VMs/Proxmox which are not NATed. The server is the typical Hetzner Server, so only on NIC but multiple IPs or/subnets on this NIC.

Due to the cluster-blocker with the [PCI-passthrough setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44150668/3625317) this is my alternative

1. Proxmox Server with 1 NIC(eth0)
2. 3 Public 1IPs, IP2/3 are routed by MAC in the datacenter (to eth0)
3. KVM bridged setup ( eth0 no ip, vmbr0 bridged to eth0 with IP1 )
4. A private LAN on vmbr30, 10.1.7.0/24
5. A shorewall on the proxmox server

To better outline the setup, i create this [drawing](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Proxmox%20OPNsense%20Networking.xml#Uhttps%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FEugenMayer%2Fdrawings%2Fmaster%2FProxmox%2520OPNsense%2520Networking.xml): (not sure its perfect, tell me what to improve)

[image]

### Textual description:

#### Network interfaces on Proxmox

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    pre-up sleep 2

auto vmbr0
# docs at  
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  External-IP1(148.x.y.a)
    netmask  255.255.255.192

    # Our gateway is reachable via Point-to-Point tunneling
    # put the Hetzner gateway IP address here twice
    gateway  DATACENTER-GW1
    pointopoint DATACENTER-GW1

    # Virtual bridge settings
    # this one is bridging physical eth0 interface
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    pre-up sleep 2
    bridge_maxwait 0
    metric 1

    # Add routing for up to 4 dedicated IP's we get from Hetzner
    # You need to

    # opnsense
    up route add -host External-IP2(148.x.y.b)/32 dev vmbr0
    # rancher
    up route add -host External-IP2(148.x.y.c)/32 dev vmbr0

    # Assure local routing of private IPv4 IP's from our
    # Proxmox host via our firewall's WAN port
    up ip route add 10.1.7.0/24 via External-IP2(148.x.y.b) dev vmbr0

auto vmbr30
iface vmbr30 inet static
    address  10.1.7.2
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    pre-up sleep 2
    metric 1
```

#### Shorewall on Proxmox

interfaces

```
wan     eth0            detect          dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs
wan     vmbr0           detect          bridge
lan     vmbr30          detect          bridge
```

policies:

```
lan             lan             ACCEPT          -               -
fw              all             ACCEPT          -               -
all             all             REJECT          INFO               -
```

### OPNsense

1. WAN is ExternalIP2, attached to vmbr0 with MAC-XX
2. LAN is 10.1.7.1, attached to vmbr30

## What is working:

- The basic setup works fine, i can access opnsense with IP2, i can access proxmox on IP1 and i can access rancher-VM on ip3 - that is what does not need any routing.
- i can connect with a IPSec mobile client to OPNsense, offering access to LAN (10.1.7.0/24) from a virtual ip range 172.16.0.0/24
- i can  access 10.1.7.1 ( opnsense ) while connected with OpenVPN
- i can access 10.1.7.11 / 10.1.7.151 from OPNsense(10.1.7.1) (shell)
- i can access 10.1.7.11 / 10.1.7.1 from othervm(10.1.7.151) (shell)

## Whats not working:

a) connecting to 10.1.7.11/10.1.7.151 or 10.1.7.2 from the IPsec client

b) [SOLVED in UPDATE 1]connecting to 10.1.7.2 from 10.1.7.1 (opnsense)

c) Its seems like i have asynchron routing, and while i can access e.g. 10.1.7.1:8443 i see a lot if entries

[image: c) the norm]

d) IPSec LAN sharing would include i rule in IPSEC chain, "from * to LAN ACCEPT" - but that did not work for me, i had to add "from * to * ACCEPT"[image]

---

## Questions:

I) Of course i want to fix a)b)c)d), probably starting with understanding c) and d)

II) would it help, in this setup, to add a second NIC?

III) could it be an issue that i activated net.ipv4.ip_forward on the proxmox host ( shouldnt it be routed rather? )

When i got this straighten out i would love to place a comprehensive guide on how to run OPNsense as a Appliance with a private network in on Proxmox, passing some services to the outer world using HAproxe+LE and also accessing the private lan using IPsec

#### UPDATE1:

Removing `up ip route add 10.1.7.0/24 via IP2 dev vmbr0` from vmbr0 on proxmox fixed the issue that neither proxmox could access 10.1.7.0/24 nor it could have been access from the LAN network.

#### UPDATE2:

I created an updated / changed setup where pci-passthrough is used. Goals are the same - it reduces the complexity - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134651/proxmox-with-opnsense-as-pci-passthrough-setup-used-as-firewall-router-ipsec-pri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some direly needed rough basics first:

- There's routing, which is IP's and packets on layer3.
- There's switching, which is MAC's and frames on layer2.

Further you speak of vmbr0/1/30, but only 0 and 30 are shown in your config.
Shorewall does not matter for your vm connectivity (iptables is layer3, ebtables would be layer2 for contrast, but your frames should just fly by the shorewall, not getting to the HV but instead going to the VM's directly. shorewall is just a frontend using iptables in the background).

With that out of the way:

Usually you don't need any routing on the proxmox BRIDGES. A bridge is a switch, as far as you are concerned. vmbr0 is a virtual external bridge which you linked with eth0 (thus created an in-kernel link between a physical nic and your virtual interface, to get packets to flow at all). The bridge could also run without an IP attached to it at all. But to have the HV accessible, usually an external IP is attached to it. Otherwise you'd have to setup your firewall gateway plus a VPN tunnel, give vmbr30 an internal ip, and  then you could access the internal IP of the HV from the internet after establishing a tunnel connnection, but that's just for illustration purposes for now.

Your ipsec connectivity issue sounds an awful lot like a misconfigured VPN, but also mobile IPSEC is just often a pain in the butt to work with due to protocol implementation differences, openvpn works a LOT better, but you should know your basics about PKI and certificates to implement that. Plus if opnsense is as counter-intuitive as pfsense when it comes to openvpns, you are possibly in for a week of stabbing at the dark easily. For pfsense there's a installable openvpn config export package which makes life quite easier, don't know wether this one is available for opnsense, too.

It does not so much look like what you call asynchronous routing but rather like a firewall issue you had, concerning the first picture.
For your tunnel firewall (interface IPSEC or interface openvpn on opnsense, depending on the tunnel you happen to use) just leave it at ipv4 any:any to any:any, you should only get into the LAN net anyway by the definition of the tunnel itself, opnsense will automatically send the packets out from the LAN interface only, on the second picture.

`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` = enable routing in the kernel at all on the linux OS's interfaces where you activated it. You can do NAT-ting stuff via iptables, thus making it possible for getting into your LAN by using your external HV IP on vmbr0 in theory, but that's not something you should happen to achieve by accident, you might be able to disable forwarding again without loosing connectivity. At least to the HV, I am unsure about is your extra routes for the other external IPs, but these should be configurable the same way from within the opnsense directly (create the point-to-point links there, the frames will transparently flow through vmbr0 and eth0 to the hetzner gateway) and work, which would be cleaner.

Also you should not make the rancher-VM accessible externally directly and thus bypassing your firewall, I doubt this is what you want to achieve. Rather put the external ip onto the opnsense (as virtual ip of type ip alias), set up 1:1 NAT from IP3 to the internal ip of the rancher-vm, and do the firewalling via opnsense.

Some ascii art how things possibly should look from what I can discern from your information so far, for the sake of brevity only interfaces are used, no distinction is made between physical/virtual servers, and no point-to-point links are shown.

```
[hetzner gw]
  |
  |
  |
[eth0] (everything below happens inside your server)
  ||
  || (double lines here to hint at the physical-virtual linking linux does)
  || (which is achieved by linking eth0 to vmbr0)
  ||
  || +-- HV acess to via IP1 -- shorewall/iptables for hv firewalling 
  || |
[vmbr0]                                                    [vmbr30]
 IP1                                                        | | |
  |                                                         | | |
  |                                                         | | |
[wan nic opn]                                               | | | 
  IP2 on wan directly,                                      | | |
  IP3 as virtual IP of type ip alias                        | | |
  x                                                         | | |
  x (here opn does routing/NAT/tunnel things)               | | |
  x                                                         | | |
  x set up 1:1 NAT IP3-to-10.1.7.11 in opn for full access  | | |
  x set up single port forwardings for the 2nd vm if needed | | |
  x                                                         | | |
[lan nic opn]-----------------------------------------------+ | |
 10.1.7.1                                                     | |
                                                              | |
                                                   +----------+ |
                                                   |            |
                                              [vm1 eth0]   [vm2 eth0]
                                               10.1.7.11    10.1.7.151
```

If you want to firewall the HV via opnsense, too, these would be the steps to do so while maintainting connectivity:

1. remove IP1 from [vmbr0]
2. put it on [wan nic opn]
3. put internal ip (IP_INT) from opn lan onto [vmbr30]
4. set up 1:1 NAT from IP
5. set all firewall rules
6. swear like hell when you break the firewall and cannot reach the hv anymore
7. see wether you can access the HV via an iKVM solution hoping to get a public IP onto it, so you can use the console window in proxmox hoping to fix or reinstall the firewall.

Comment: wow. I will work through all of this! for the vmbr0 / putting HV behind the FW i currently decided to rather do a PCI passthrough completly and handling anything in OPNsense the. I would say, that makes even more sense in this regard - what do you think - i hava a LARA/Serial Console to the server? I already elaborated / worked on the 1:1 option, thank you. And really thank you for smashing my head against routing/switching. I will get back to it just after i worked through it - will take time to process. At least i got a downvote without a comment why, thats helpful in general :)

Comment: No pci passthrough is needed, the bridge will take care of getting your packets through, and just use iptables on the HV. Anything else means just unneeded pain somewhere along the way.

Comment: Also get a grip how things work with switching/routing. A Gateway is only needed for packets which need to be routed since they need to get out of the broadcast domain (thats a switching thing). Learn what ARP does. Use some wireshark locally. Really learn the OSI model, a last hint not related to all the other stuff: TCP/UDP = Segments/Datagrams = Ports = layer4

Comment: PIC passthrough in that regared was due to the degraded performance of virtio NIC in the opnsense box which i would like to circumvent. But i understood that putting the bridge the way you told solves that also, but not the performance issue ( which is not a topic we have here, of course ). Will go through the OSI model and refresh it, will focus on switching/routing. Once again, thank you already!

Comment: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/VirtIO_Driver_Support / https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/PfSense_Guest_Notes might apply here, too. You can also still use e1000 instead of virtio nics. Do you really hit the perfomance boundaries?

Comment: yes it is well known - most of the docs you link here are outdated, based on FreeBSD10, 11.1 has far better and build in virtio support, but far away from native speed. The biggest issue is checksum offloading which needs to be disabled if you use virtio, creating quiet some load. You actually do disable tx on vmbr0  also, its not part of the past above, but it would be needed

Comment: Seems you know more than I do.

Comment: do you mind me changing the initial question with pci-passthrough? i eliminated some issues already, removes shorewall from the equasion and overall simplifies a lot of things. A lot of your answer remains right, but it would need adjustments. I could create a new question but i think that does not make sense, or if you say so, means, you expect hat the above setup will work without your suggestion, we can leave this one here and move forward to the "other setup" if you will

Comment: i went forward here after i recognized how much this question would be changing when writing up the article - i posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134651/proxmox-with-opnsense-as-pci-passthrough-setup-used-as-firewall-router-ipsec-pri and yet unsure how we process this article. I would actually love to get both straightened up. I think if i reduce this question to the basic setup without IPsec questions, your answer is a perfect fit and the whole thing is very valuable as a variant. What do you think?

Comment: I basically did exactly what sjas suggested and it work really good. One thing i would remove from this answer though, or at least with a bug fat hint, thats the last part with the external IP. If that is done, you will no longer be able to use this setup in a cluster, similar to the pci-passthrough setup. So as long you do not have a dedicated NIC uplink for cluster sync, you need a direct gateway to the internet on the proxmox hv.